# Should the "Other" close reason be used when one of the standard reasons apply?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

On Stack Overflow, I frequently see people use the Off Topic -> Other close reason for questions that should be closed with one of the standard close reasons. It seems like they're just doing this so that they can combine the close vote and comment into one step.

For instance, *[Mirrors failing for RHEL 7 yum install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770480/mirrors-failing-for-rhel-7-yum-install)*. The close reason they gave is pretty similar to the "Questions about general computing hardware and software" reason (which is the close reason I chose when voting).

Should I send a message to the closer recommending that they use a standard close reason unless none of the come close to applying? Or is it not a big deal, on the assumption that other votes will probably use the standard reason, and the final closure will have that message?

Comment: Because the closer is nice, wants the question-asker to know that the question is off-topic, and offers help before the question is closed (which may not happen at all)?

Comment: He can do that by voting to close with a standard reason and also adding a comment explaining why.

Comment: They are combining it into one step

Comment: I vote to close as other if more than one reason is applicable on the post.

Comment: @SagarV That's what I said: **they're just doing this so that they can combine the close vote and comment into one step**. Do you consider that an appropriate reason to use "Other"?